# How to register performance counters so that I don't have to be an administrator to see them?

Tags: c#, permissions, performancecounter

I have created some custome performance counters and an application to install them.

I can install them fine if I run the install tool as administrator and if I run `typeperf -q` from the command line I can see my counters.

If I run perfmon as administrator I can see the counters listed, but if I run perfmon as a 'normal user' then my performance counters are not listed in the list.

This is all on the local machine.

The counters are created like so:

```
var countersToCreate = new CounterCreationDataCollection();

countersToCreate.Add(CreateCounter(
            String.Format(CounterNameOperationCount, OperationName),
            PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems64));
///
... add more counters
///
PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(
        CategoryName,
        CategoryName,
        PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance,
        countersToCreate);
```

**UPDATE**

My app is built targeting x86. The problem seems to related to how the perf mon tool is launched.  If I launch it from the shortcut in Administrative Tools or from the exe in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ then I can see my counters. If I launch it using Lanchy then I can't see my counters, and worse, the counters then not seen when I launch perfmon from one of the shortcuts that previously worked, until I uninstall and reinstall them.

Strange but I seem to have got to the bottom of the issue and I'll just stop using launchy to open the perf counters app.

Comment: what is the OS you are using this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in group Performance Monitor Users. Adding your non admin user to that group should fix the problem.

Comment: But don't you need to be admin to add users to that group?

Comment: No need to be admin just need to be in group

Comment: hmm.. I'm not sure if this helped but I've edited the question with some extra info.  Seems unrelated to launching as admin, as I'd first thought

Comment: I tried but failed, my scenario is: my web app using `PerformanceCounterCategory` is host in IIS, the application pool's user is not an administrator, I've already added the user to the 'Performance Monitor Users' group, but in runtime the UnauthorizedAccessException still raises